# I am using laravel 5.4 and php 7.2 and come asross following issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\ApiContactController, because the name is already in use

ApiContactController code is following

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contact;
use App\Http\Resources\Contact\ContactResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
class ApiContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = "Hello";
        return new ContactResource( $data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function create_profile(Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'name' =>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // Validation failed
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => $validator->messages(),
            ]);
        }else{
            $contact=Contact::whereNumber($request->number)->update([
                'verified_name' => $request->name?$request->name:null,
                'email'         =>$request->email?$request->email:null
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'Successfully Profile Updated',
        ]);

    }
}
```

How to resolve above mention problem if exist in my code. Suggest me a easy way to solve this issue.
Already i have tried diffrent solution from different sources but still i have this error

Comment: Try `use ..... AS something`. Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I have struggled before as well. And this did it for me.

Comment: Try use.......... AS something? what solution this is?

Comment: why do not you try changing the controller name?

Comment: check your controllers folder their might be another controller with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how many class you have with class name ApiContactController and see if you have same namespace for all those files. If you have same namespaces in diff folder it should be fine, but if you have same folder then you don't have anyother option except changing the class name

Answer (score 0):

please put this line after the namespace, The class which you are trying to extend. Not sure this will solve your problem,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```